# fast deletion in a list with too many elements - PYTHON

Tags: python, python-itertools

How can I quickly delete elements in b from inside a ?

```
import itertools

a=list(itertools.product("12X",repeat=15))
b=list(itertools.product("1X",repeat=15))
print("a len = ",len(a))
print("b len = ",len(b))

for x in b:
    if x in a:
        a.remove(x)
```

It's very slow.

Comment: So you only want the elements of `a` that contain a `2`? Can you just generate that sequence directly, rather than having to filter a pre-generated list?

Comment: `a = [x for x in product("12X", repeat=15) if '2' in x]`.

Comment: @chepner My purpose is different , numbers is representation , I just wanted to learn the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the lists to sets and just subtract.

```
import itertools

a=list(itertools.product("123",repeat=3))
b=list(itertools.product("12",repeat=3))
print("a len = ",len(a))
print("b len = ",len(b))
c = set(a) - set(b)
print(len(c))

# This is the equivalent of
c = set(a).difference(set(b))

>>> a len =  27
>>> b len =  8
>>> 19
```

You can also do `set(a).intersection(set(b))` in order to return those that appear in both lists.

If order matters, just use a list comprehension:

```
excluded_elems = set(b)
c = [x for x in a if x not in excluded_elems]
print(len(c))
```

Make sure to compute `set(b)` once, outside the comprehension, instead of inlining it in the `not in` check, which would compute it on every iteration.

Comment: This is good but has the potential drawback of possibly changing the order of the remaining elements in `a`.

Comment: @JohnColeman updated to accommodate for order with basic list comp

Comment: The comprehension could use `set(b)`.

Comment: For optimisation yes, since checking in a set is faster than checking in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
c = set(b)
a = [ x for x in a if x in c]
```

Comment: Seems a bit backwards. `c` contains the elements that you want to keep but your comprehension explicitly excludes them.

Comment: Sorry, editing the answer.